# How do I enable PHPUnit testing for a sandbox project on drupal.org?

Tags: testing, community-official-site

This questions is specifically about my sandbox project. I have PHPUnit running on other full projects that I maintain.

I have created a sandbox project, fully uploaded to drupal.org, for 8.x and 9.x testing. But there is no "Automated testing" tab on the project page, like there is with full projects. What has to be done to enable testing on drupal.org?

The project has a composer.json, .info.yml and drupalci.yml. My phpunit tests run locally. Everything looks fine. I have searched drupal.org docs https://www.drupal.org/node/1011196 and it does not say that phpunit testing is not available for sandbox projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the following comment I found on [Can enable tests for sandbox projects](https://www.drupal.org/project/project_issue_file_test/issues/2245089), testing is disabled on sandbox projects, which means you cannot enable automatic tests on sandbox projects.

> From `pift_project_visibility()`:
>
> ```
> if (!empty($node->field_project_has_releases[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'])) {
> // Ensure user has the 'access project testing tab' permission
> if (user_access('access pift project testing tab')) {
>   return TRUE;
> }
> ```
>
> }
>
> So as long as the releases piece is taken care of, the 'enable' checkbox should never appear (and thus users will not be able to enable testing).

The issue has been created in the project that handles the automatic testing for projects hosted on drupal.org. The comment says that the automatic tests are enabled for the projects with enabled releases. Sandbox projects don't have releases enabled, so also the automatic tests are disabled.

As Drupal.org Git administrator I can confirm that none of the sandbox projects has the *Automated testing* tab, which I instead see on full projects. (It's not a matter of permissions, as my role on Drupal.org allows me to set automatic tests for any project.)

To answer [How did you enable automated testing on this sandbox project?](https://www.drupal.org/project/captchasandbox/issues/3125275) that project has automatic tests enabled because it's a full project, despite the project name. I can say that because the path alias automatically set for a sandbox project is similar to `https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/grayside/1876908`, the path alias for the [#Heading](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/grayside/1876908) module. Furthermore, a sandbox project has a *Promote* tab as in the following screenshot.

> [image: screenshot]

For the other project, this is what I see.

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks @kiamlaluno I presume there is no plan to allow automated testing on sandbox projects? It would really help at the moment for D9 testing where I don't want to confuse the real module code with temporary commits, but some patches need to patch composer.json to allow the D9 tests to even run (such as removing require-dev for modules which cannot be installed on 9.x)

Comment: The idea behind sandbox projects was allowing users to create projects before they applied to be able to create full projects. Now that every user is able to create full projects, there are very few reasons for enabling testing on sandbox projects. I am not sure it would be technically possible; probably, automatic testing requires releases, which will never be enabled for sandbox projects.

Comment: Thanks.  kiamlaluno has also posted useful info on https://www.drupal.org/project/captchasandbox/issues/3125275